# php Fat Free, how to use captcha plugin

Tags: php, frameworks, captcha, fat-free-framework

I can't use the Captcha plugin provided by [Fat Free](http://fatfree.sourceforge.net/)

Please help me

```
F3::route ( 'GET /captcha',captcha);

function captcha(){
    F3::captcha(100,100,8);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be:

`F3::route ( 'GET /captcha','captcha');`

Comment: PHP should really get first-class functions so you don't have to mess with strings in cases like this...

Answer (score 1):

Fix so easy!
http://techzinger.blogspot.com/2011/02/fat-free-framework-for.html?showComment=1298024374012#c4330544534362949394

Comment: It is a good manner here, to post some explanation, not just link. Link can eventually become dead and your answer become useless in this case. Never post just links! It is considered a quite bad behavior at SE network.

Answer (score 0):

**Let F3 know where your fonts folder is**

*I have following in my index.php file*

```
define('ROOT',realpath(__dir__.'/../').'/');

F3::set('FONTS',ROOT.'fonts/');
```